# IntelliJ IDEA 13.1 debug throws Unable to open debugger port error for Play 2.3.x on Windows 7

Tags: playframework-2.3, intellij-13

We are using Play 2.3.x for our web application. I wanted to debug the server side code, so performed the following

steps on Windows 7 machine

```
1) Set the JAVA_OPTIONS to "-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9999"

2) On IntelliJ IDE : Run > Edit Configurations > Created a configuration with name "myserverdebug" with values ( transport : socket , debugger mode : attach , port : 9999 , host : localhost , modules class path : our project) and apply

3) Run > Debug > Select "myserverdebug"
```

Then the error thrown is :

> Error running ServerDebugTests: Unable to open debugger port : java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused: connect**

Can some one tell me how to resolve this connection port error on **Windows 7** ( not Linux )?

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? How?

Answer (score 1):

debugging changed in play 2.3. Just start activator with `-jvm-debug 9999`.

Afterwards your debug configuration should work.